# QuickBlox : Users not retrieved

Tags: android, quickblox

I am trying to run the out of box QuickBlox sample code : 'Sample-chat'

While running the app, I get the message on the error "Can't obtain users errors : Entity you are looking for was not found"

**Steps followed:**

a. Imported code + updated credentials

b. Created new uesrs + Gave access to allow reading all users in 'settings'

c. Run the app

**Log Details**

1. System is requesting for a token :
2. Token is provided by QuickBlox:

   '{"session":{"_id":"58149264a0eb473ec6000003","application_id":49026,"created_at":"2016-10-29T12:13:24Z","device_id":0,"nonce":-1457326446,**"token":"1c4f74dbcddce49a0893c644e6f35be82500bf82"**,"ts":1477743203,"updated_at":"2016-10-29T12:13:24Z","user_id":0,"id":7959}}'
3. System tries to get users using the 'tag'. This tag is the UserName in the Constants file. (including the token in the message)

   === REQUEST ==== 6abe774b-ff3e-45fa-88a4-b146920daa8f ===

   REQUEST
          GET https://api.quickblox.com/users/by_tags.json

   HEADERS
          QuickBlox-REST-API-Version=0.1.1
          QB-SDK=Android 3.1.0
          QB-Token=1c4f74dbcddce49a0893c644e6f35be82500bf82

   PARAMETERS
          tags=webrtcusers

   INLINE
          GET https://api.quickblox.com/users/by_tags.json?tags=webrtcusers
4. Response has no body i.e. users not found

   *** RESPONSE *** 6abe774b-ff3e-45fa-88a4-b146920daa8f ***

   STATUS : 404

   HEADERS

   ```
      X-Runtime=0.120270

      Cache-Control=no-cache

      X-Rack-Cache=miss

      QuickBlox-REST-API-Version=0.1.1

      X-UA-Compatible=IE=Edge,chrome=1

      QB-Token-ExpirationDate=2016-10-29 14:13:24 UTC

      Status=404 Not Found

      X-Request-Id=acf767ba75c0d7e17619887b61463231

      X-Android-Response-Source=NETWORK 404

      Connection=Close

      X-Android-Sent-Millis=1477743206083

      Content-Type=application/json; charset=utf-8

      Date=Sat, 29 Oct 2016 12:13:26 GMT

      Server=openresty/1.9.15.1

      Content-Length=1

      X-Android-Received-Millis=1477743207078

      Access-Control-Allow-Origin=*
      **BODY
      ' '**
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Please create 'tags' for all your users on the admin panel, and use the same tag as is provided in the sample code.